# Weighted support vector machine one against all approach in multiclassification

Tags: r, svm

I have implemented the one-against-all approach for multi-class SVM .
I want to use not standar svm model, a new extension called weighted svm proposed by https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317497469_A_Novel_Weighted_Support_Vector_Machines_Multiclass_Classifier_Based_on_Differential_Evolution_for_Intrusion_Detection_Systems?focusedCommentId=59ca9594b53d2f691d607727

Any idea how to calculate the weight of each classifier λj ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wsvm library in r packages it implements the  weighted SVM model and you have just to specify a random weight for the different class.
 To explain the notion of weights in support vector machines for multiclass problem  let's understand the theorritical view.  In case of mutoclass problem, we have more than one class in the target output, using binary svm it can manage only two classes problem one solution to muticlass problem, is to use one versus one or one versus all appproach. So the problem will be resolved as a binary problem. The idea of weighted svm(depends on the distance from a new instance and all the classes)[image] is to give weights for the different classes to manage a non linear decision boundaries between the differents classes as presented in the image below.